# How to validate Bootstrap + chosen plugin with jQuery php

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, jquery-chosen

I have made a category list for available products. I am using bootstrap + choosen plugin for multiSelect dropdown options. What i want is the user to select at least 1 option when he/she submit the form. I mean whenever the form submitted, category list should not be blank. It should be done in php according to my colleagues but i already used third party plugin for multiSelect dropdown so jQuery or php no matters. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried this

My bootstrap code and php validation code:

```
<select multiple class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select Your Category" name="category">
  <option>Product a</option>
  <option>Product b</option>
  <option>Product c</option>
  <option>Product d</option>
  <option>Product e</option>
  <option>Product f</option>
  <option>Product g</option>
  <?php
    foreach ($catlist as $category) {
      if (isset($_POST["category"]) && $_POST["category"] == $category)
        echo "<option selected='selected' value='$category'>$category</option>";
      else
        echo "<option value='$category'>$category</option>";
    }
  ?>
</select>

//define $categorylist here

$catlist = array (
  "Product a",
  "Product b",
  "Product c",
  "Product d"
  "Product e"
  "Product f"
  "Product g"
);
```

I also tried with jQuery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chosen-select').chosen({
      width: "100%",
      min_selected_options:1,
      max_selected_options:3
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post" id="form">
    <p id="message"></p>
    <select multiple class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select Your Category" id="category" name="category[]">
        <option>Product a</option>
        <option>Product b</option>
        <option>Product c</option>
        <option>Product d</option>
        <option>Product e</option>
        <option>Product f</option>
        <option>Product g</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        // console.log('errors');
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectData = $('#category').val();
        // console.log(selectData);

        if (selectData.length< 1 || selectData.length> 3) {
            $('#message').html('error').css({'color':'red'});
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url:$(location).attr('href'),
            data: selectData,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#message').html('success').css({'color':'green'});

            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this was written by ajax. This is very simple
length<1  || length> 3 :error